# Does Scala has optimizations for recursion that construct list on return value?

Tags: scala

I have read posts mentioned that Scala has a tail recursion optimization.

But how about this one:

```
def f(i: Int): List[Int] = {
  if (i == 0)
    Nil
  else
    i :: f(i - 1) // Is there any optimizations?
}
```

The line 5 is not a tail recursion.

Does Scala has some kind of optimizations on it? Or it may consume much more stack spaces then its imperative version?

Comment: When the function is not tail-recursive, the function will use more stack space. You can use the `@tailrec` annotation on the function to make the compiler give an error if your function could not be tail-call optimized.

Comment: Hi @Pavel , actually this is not a tail recursion. To confirm that I have just add the annotation which in marstran's comment. Then the compiler raised an error: _could not optimize \@tailrec annotated method f: it contains a recursive call not in tail position_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it currently stands this code will compute each recursion in a separate stack frame. If `i` is sufficiently large then you run out of memory.

```
scala> f(10000)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at .f(<console>:15)
  at .f(<console>:15)
  at .f(<console>:15)
```

So the compiler can do little to help make this more efficient.

You can either guard against `i` being too large (if that works for your requirement but is not very nice perhaps), or else make it tail recursive so it can be computed in constant stack space.

As an example.

```
scala> @tailrec def f(i: Int, x: List[Int] = List()): List[Int] = {
     |   if (i == 0)
     |     x.reverse
     |   else
     |     f(i - 1, i :: x)
     | }

f: (i: Int, x: List[Int])List[Int]

scala> f(10)
res10: List[Int] = List(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Note that the reversal of the list (`x.reverse`) before returning it is `0(n)` (complexity) but only necessary if you need it in reverse order obviously.

Comment: Note that `@tailrec` only makes sures that call will be recursive -- proper code would be optimized by compiler even without it

Comment: That is correct - it is a compile time only report on whether it is possible to confine the computation within the bounds of a single stack frame.

Comment: Another (mutable) slightly more effective solution would be using of `ListBuffer`, that really could append elements to the `List` having private knowledge that `tail` is a `var` in the `::`

Answer (score 2):

Use scalaz trampoline

```
 object tail {

 def f(i: Int): Trampoline[List[Int]] = {
   if (i == 0)
     Trampoline.done(Nil)
   else
     Trampoline.suspend(f(i - 1)).flatMap { list =>
       Trampoline.done((i :: list))
     }
 }

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit  = {
   println(f(1000).run)
 }

}
```

And there wont be stack problems

Comment: Don't use trampoline, unless you are 100% sure what you do.

Comment: While I dont thing that `Trampoline` is a good solution for stack problems outside Monad transformers, I fill the urge to recover this answer rating back to plain 0.

Comment: Another point would be that both `scalaz` and `cats` `Trampoline`s would do automatic `suspend` on `flatMap`, so `Trampoline.suspend` call is excessive